# Falhas de design do Javascript

Tags: javascript

Em um mundo onde existem linguagens fortemente tipadas como `C++`, `Java` ou `Pascal`, por que ainda `Javascript` é usado, apesar de todas suas falhas (como ausência de escopo por bloco e facilidade exagerada de criação de variáveis globais)?

Comment: Isso parece pergunta para trabalho de faculdade...

Comment: Matheus, bem vindo ao Stackoverflow! Este site existe para dar respostas a problemas concretos de código. Discussões mais gerais não cabem aqui como perguntas. Pode ser um assunto para o chat mas como pergunta está fora de tópico. Assim se tiver um bug, poste aqui que a gente dá uma ajuda.

Comment: Obrigado Sergio.

Comment: E desde quando ausência de escopo por bloco é uma falha?

Comment: Matheus, a pergunta foi fechada por não ser adequada ao formato do site. Porém você pode editar a pergunta, tornando-a mais específica e menos subjetiva (recomendo fortemente a leitura de [Good subjective, bad subjective](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective)). Se conseguir transformá-la em algo que possa ser respondido em alguns parágrafos, tenho certeza que vários usuários votarão para reabrir (eu incluso!).

Comment: A pergunta é de mais de dois anos atrás, mas vale um comentário: Ausência de escopo por bloco por si só não é critério de decisão. Facilidade de criação de globais, por si só, tambem não. Tipos fortes ou não são geralmente são insuficientes para escolha. Além disso (já respondido), como JS é a única opção verdadeira client-side, acaba sendo necessário usar de qualquer forma. Java tem problemas, C++ é burocrática demais para alguns contextos, pascal tem seus problemas também. Falhas de conceito dão noção errada dos valores relevantes para escolha. Precisa analisar o conjunto todo.

Answer (score 1):

Porque javascript é a única linguagem de programação client-side. E com bom senso é possível criar aplicativos web incríveis.

Comment: Concordo, mas a resposta é complexa e vai além disso, pois javascript tende a ser também amplamente utilizado em server-side com iniciativas como Node.js

Comment: Exatamente! Poderíamos falar sobre vários assuntos relacionados à linguagem JS, mas não vale a pena.

Comment: Existem outras linguagens para client side. Flash ainda não morreu, e existem linguagens construídas sobre Javascript.

Comment: @Renan, poderia falar quais linguagens são construídas sobre JavaScript?

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi eis uma lista (de forma alguma exaustiva) delas: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS algumas, como `coffeescript`, são feitas para serem usadas client-side.

Comment: Vi pouco de CoffeeScript, olhei sem querer no jsFiddle e apareceu a opção, mas ainda não vi a fundo sintaxe, benefícios e etc. De qualquer maneira, obrigado.